# Android Volley Convert JSONArray to ArrayList<MyObject>

Tags: java, android, gson, android-volley

I have JsonObject

[JSON Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmSCj.png)

I have method which return JSONArray. I want to pass first field and get only data array. And then cast it to my Array List. I will really appriciated for any suggestion from you.

```
  void getUsersBeacons(){
    type = new TypeToken<List<Beacon>>(){}.getType();
    JSONArray myReq = new JSONArray(Request.Method.GET, Url + testId + Url2, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            try{
            JSONArray buffArray = response.getJSONArray(2);
               JSONArray bufJsonArray = response.getJSONArray(1);
                beaconsList = converter.fromJson(bufJsonArray.toString(), type);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    });
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(myReq);
}
```

Beacon class:

```
public class Beacon {

private Object idBeacon;
private String friendlyName;
private String imageUrl;

public Beacon(Object idBeacon, String friendlyName, String imageUrl) {
    this.idBeacon = idBeacon;
    this.friendlyName = friendlyName;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public Object getIdBeacon() {
    return idBeacon;
}

public void setIdBeacon(Object idBeacon) {
    this.idBeacon = idBeacon;
}

public String getFriendlyName() {
    return friendlyName;
}

public void setFriendlyName(String friendlyName) {
    this.friendlyName = friendlyName;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you better pass in JSONArray instead of string and parse it's contents, like this:

```
public static List<Beacon> fromJson(JSONArray array)
{
  ArrayList<Beacon> res = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); ++i)
  {
    JSONObject beacon = array.getJSONObject(i);
    res.add(new Beacon(beacon.getInt("beaconId"), beacon.getString("name"), beacon.getString("imageUrl"))));
  }

  return res;
}
```

UPD: in response to your comment, you must use `Response.Listener<JSONObject>` instead of `Response.Listener<JSONArray>`, and then do this:

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
{
  JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("data");
  converter.fromJson(array);
}
```

Comment: Yeap, but i have the same error over and over
https://imgur.com/shHyTgD

Comment: JSONArray bufJsonArray = response.getJSONArray(1);
 fromJson(bufJsonArray);

Comment: I've made it firstfully

Comment: You're trying to get an array instead of object, that's why you get the error. Try using `getJSONObject()` instead